# Contain multiple page templates in one PHP custom template file in Wordpress?

Tags: php, functions, hooks, page-template, get-template-part

As we know that WP has a feature called Page_Templates. But today, I got a question in my mind that can we add/use/access multiple page templates from single .php file (which is responsible to call page template.)

For example first 40 lines of demo-xyz.php will echo a "demo" page template and then after left lines echo a "xyz" template. then i want to select both as page template for different two pages in wordpress>pages>addnew>page attributes>select page template. (there both 1.demo & 2.xyz template name should be shown)

**example (file:demo-xyz.php)-**

```
/*
Template : demo
*/

....Codes For template demo

/*
Template : xyz
*/

.... Codes for template xyz
```

Reason - I have multiple page templates and i am finding me unable to manage too much template files that's why i wanna it's solution.

I searched everywhere for it but not find out a solution anywhere

Comment: No, this isn't possible. I misunderstood your previous version of this question and thought you meant the opposite. Frankly, this seems way harder to maintain.

Comment: thanks @JacobPeattie Now i have to use shortcode (which can be maintained in one file) to insert php into pages/posts..

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, a PHP file can only contain a single page template. There is no way to combine the files.